# Mobile menu hides automatically when I scroll down my page

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, menu

I have this website and when I'm scrolling down my mobile menu automatically hides if it is opened.

What I want is that for example users clicks on it and displays the menu. This issue is happening only on mobile. I've already changed CSS adding z-index or display:block in some elements but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thanks.

Comment: check your media queries and conditional css

Comment: one way to check is using your desktop browser and open the developer tab and turn on mobile preview then you can inspect which styles are really being used.

Comment: Add some code, please! A CodePen link or URL to your site would be helpful.